# Azure DevOps Build WinUI App Fails: Missing dll Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, winui

I'm trying to build our executable, which is working locally and is built and published in Visual Studio. Now we're trying to get it working the an Azure DevOps build pipeline and the publish task fails. The pipeline spec we're using is:

```yaml
variables:
  - name: solution
    value: '**/*.sln'
  - name: viewSolution
    value: 'prj\prj.sln'
  - name: testConfiguration
    value: 'Debug'
  - name: releaseConfiguration
    value: 'Release'
  - group: buildtime_configuration_variables_dev

jobs:
- job: Build

  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'

  steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: "Set .NET SDK Version"
    inputs:
      version: '6.0.x'

  - task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
    inputs:
      packageFeedSelector: 'nugetOrg'
      versionSelector: 'latestStable'

  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
    displayName: 'NuGet Install'

  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: 'NuGet Restore'
    inputs:
      restoreSolution: $(solution)

  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: "Install Windows App Runtime"
    inputs:
      script: 'prj\WindowsAppRuntimeInstall.exe --quiet'

  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: "Adding build number to Exe"
    inputs:
      targetType: "inline"
      script: |
        sed -i "s|DEVBUILDVERSION|$(Build.BuildNumber)|g" **/**/**/Settings.cs
      
  - task: VSBuild@1
    displayName: 'Build release solution'
    inputs:
      solution: $(viewSolution)
      configuration: $(releaseConfiguration)
      msbuildArguments: '/t:restore;rebuild;publish /p:SelfContained=true /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:Configuration=$(releaseConfiguration) /p:RuntimeIdentifier=win10-x64'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      arguments: '-c $(releaseConfiguration) --runtime win10-x64 --self-contained --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) -p:IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract=true'
      zipAfterPublish: false
      projects: prj
      workingDirectory: prj
      publishWebProjects: false
    displayName: Publish Build

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: 'Publish MidasView ZIP'
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

So we fail on the "Publish Build" task (second from the bottom) with the error message:

```
...
C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\microsoft.windowsappsdk\1.2.221109.1\buildTransitive\MrtCore.PriGen.targets(380,5): error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.GetSdkFileFullPath" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\6.0.411\\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\6.0.411\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.dll'. The system cannot find the path specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [D:\a\1\s\MidasView\MidasView.Test\MidasView.Test.csproj]
...
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
...
```

I've checked to see if that path actually exists by adding in a step to list the directories along that path and the path is valid up to and including `\Microsoft\`, but there is no `VisualStudio\` contained therein. I've tried searching for this error thinking maybe I needed to install it by setting the runtime or sdk versions or maybe there's a package missing, but so far no luck. Where am I going wrong?

**UPDATE**: We gave up on trying to build into a single executable and are instead opting for an installer approach. We were trying to avoid our users needing to copy a bunch of files around, but with an installer we can simply do that programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, it looks like Microsoft recommends using pipeline artifacts instead of build artifacts:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#migrate-from-build-artifacts

Something like this:

```
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: 'Publish MidasView ZIP'
  inputs:
    targetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**
    artifactType: 'pipeline'
```

Comment: Yeah, it's still there from a few years ago, just haven't gotten around to updating it. Not the source of the issues